# Использование div в качестве input

Tags: html, html5, вёрстка

Как-то уже натыкался на такой вопрос тут, но не могу найти ни тут, ни в Интернете.
Я помню, что это какой-то атрибут, который вешается на div, но не помню какой.
И ещё вопрос: будет ли сабмитится форма (передаваться параметры при наличии соответствующих тегах) при таком самодельном input?

Comment: @webDev_ возможно про этот атрибут. Правда тогда интересует второй вопрос, будет ли это работать с формами?

Comment: @webDev_ ну да, ожидаемо. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<div contenteditable="true">edit</div>
```

нет. это по сути тот же `div`, но с возможностью его редактировать. придётся воспользоваться `JS`.